# CMS on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, content-management-system

I recently stumbled upon http://www.vosao.org/.

It seems to be the most advanced CMS for App engine.

Before I start coding with vosao, I wanted to know if there are tangible alternatives to Vosao?

Comment: This belongs on webmasters - it's not really about programming.

Comment: @NickJohnson you are right, would be nice if a user with enough priviledge would move the question

Answer (score 1):

If you are to use Vosao, you can find the content management related functions that can be invoke from velocity template in [VelocityService.java](http://code.google.com/p/vosao/source/browse/trunk/api/src/main/java/org/vosao/velocity/VelocityService.java) . Vosao separate "Page" and "Resource"

Comment: Wow, I have been searching all over for this.  A very belated, but heartfelt thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A [search](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=gae+cms&projectsearch=Search+projects) on Google Code throws up many results.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently moved off of my old Rackspace server running Joomla to Vosao on GAE and I've been very happy with it so far. I looked at a few Django alternatives, but Vosao seemed to be the simplest for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Today we released a Framework, written in python, wich is attached with a package including an exampleproject. This "Projekt" has features like: News/CMS/Shop/Forum ...

It's open Source and you can download it here:

http://www.viur.is

We are still translating some documentation to english ... so stay tuned...